# Modify tmap legend patch for hatched "polygon"

Tags: r, spatial, tmap

I want to highlight specific areas of a tmap (ex survey area within a larger landscape) using a crosshatch, so that the underlying habitat values (indicated with fill colour) are visible.  Hatched polygons do not seem to be available tmap (and other leaflet adjacent mapping options) so I am converting the focal area to a hatch using the hatchedLayer() function from the cartography package that give the appearance of a hatched polygon by creating a linestring geometry that spans the polygon boundaries.  This crated the desired map output, except for the legend, since the layer is a linestring the legend patch is a single line.  Is there a method that I can coerce tmap to draw the legend patch for the layer to reflect the hatching pattern observed on the map, or another approach to achieve the same goal? I have found way to achieve this with ggplot and few other helper packages, however I woudl prefer to have a tmap based solutions so the same workflow can be used in both interactive and static maps.

Here is an example with the NC dataset.

```
library(sf)
library(cartography)
library(tmap)
library(tidyverse)


nc <-  st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"), quiet = TRUE) 


ASHE_HASH <- hatchedLayer(x = nc %>%
  filter(NAME=="Ashe"), pattern = "diamond", mode="sfc", density=0.25, lwd=2.5) %>%
  st_as_sf() %>%
    mutate(label="test hatch")



tmap_mode("plot")


tm_shape(nc)+
  tm_polygons(col = "NAME")+
  tm_shape(ASHE_HASH)+
  tm_lines(col="label", palette = "black", lwd = 2)
```

Comment: I don't think so - the legend style is dependent on the layer type and the legend isn't flexible enough to let you design a custom legend element, which you'd then have to implement in JS to make it work in the browser. Could you make your overlay polygon partially transparent using the `alpha` parameter?

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  I can use semi transparent overlays, but that usually impacts how the lower colours look which makes the maps a little more difficult to interpret.  Hoping patterned fills/hatching becomes something available in interactive/webmaps in the future, but as I understand it the underlying methods that support how those maps are made make it fairly tricky to achieve.

Comment: How about drawing the outline only of the polygon, and the hatch lines, but then only putting the polygon in the legend? If you make the outline distinctive colour then it will show as a box of that colour outline in the legend, it just won't show the hatching.

Comment: I did also include a border in maps I've been playing with beyond the NC example, tm_borders is more set up to take a named colour, and even when tweaking by assigning a variable of named colours, the discrepancies between the legend and the map I don't think ready to be used in reports where naïve reader need to understand what is being shown.